# Insert using existing values or defaults if no record exists

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database table called Records with the columns:

```
RecordID
UserID
Total_Questions
Total_Correct_Questions
Total_Wrong_Questions
Total_Quzies_Played
```

The database table is currently empty, beside recordID and UserId all other columns have a default value of 0 .

What I'm trying to do in the SQL statement below is I'm trying to insert values into the columns e.g.  INSERT into the column Total_Questions    the current value of Total_Questions  + the given value (int @TotalQuestions)

It's something like an update but the database table is empty therefore you can't update it, it just adds the current value to the given value to update it.

However I keep getting an error

> 'Invalid column name 'Total_Questions'.
> Invalid column name 'Total_Correct_Answers'.
> Invalid column name 'Total_Wrong_Answer'.
> Invalid column name 'Total_Quizes_Played'.'

I have ran the debugger and all the variables have a value in them (the value given).
I have tried numerous things but I can't find a solution, does anyone know what's going on here?

```cs
private void Records()
{
    int UserID = Program.UserID;
   

    this.dbConnectionPath = String.Format(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\GayLord\Desktop\Quiz Game Official By Florian - Copy\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
    connectionString = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionPath);
   
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO [Records] ([Total_Questions] , [Total_Correct_Answers] , [Total_Wrong_Answers] , [Total_Quizes_Played] , [UserID]) VALUES ([Total_Questions] + @totalQuestions , [Total_Correct_Answers] + @correctCount  , [Total_Wrong_Answer] + @wrongCount , [Total_Quizes_Played] + 1 , @UserID)";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connectionString))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@totalQuestions", SqlDbType.Int).Value = totalQuestions;
        command.Parameters.Add("@correctCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = correctCount;
        command.Parameters.Add("@wrongCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = wrongCount;
        command.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID;
        connectionString.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connectionString.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the database is empty then ` current value of Total_Questions + the given value` doesn't make sense? Please show some sample data and expected results to explain what you mean.

Comment: Current values of

Comment: @DaleK  Current values of totalQuestion is 4 , the default value of the table is 0 , when the statment is ran the result should be , INSERT into Total_Questions Value Total_Question(which is 0)  + totalQuestion(which is 4) , after this Total_Questions should be 4 in the Database , if the query is ran again and  totalQuestion new value is 2 then it should do the following : INSERT into Total_Questions Value Total_Question(which is 4)  + totalQuestion(which is 2) , the Total_Question now should have a value of 6

Comment: [edit] your clarifications directly into the question please. And clarify, after some records have been inserted, how do you know which is the most recent?

Answer (score -1):

When there are no records in the table, your columns actually have a value of `NULL` - and adding a value to `NULL` is still `NULL`.

Try changing the line:

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO [Records] ([Total_Questions] , [Total_Correct_Answers] , [Total_Wrong_Answers] , [Total_Quizes_Played] , [UserID]) VALUES ([Total_Questions] + @totalQuestions , [Total_Correct_Answers] + @correctCount  , [Total_Wrong_Answer] + @wrongCount , [Total_Quizes_Played] + 1 , @UserID)";
```

to this:

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO [Records] ([Total_Questions] , [Total_Correct_Answers] , [Total_Wrong_Answers] , [Total_Quizes_Played] , [UserID]) VALUES (ISNULL([Total_Questions],0) + @totalQuestions , ISNULL([Total_Correct_Answers],0) + @correctCount  , ISNULL([Total_Wrong_Answer],0) + @wrongCount , ISNULL([Total_Quizes_Played],0) + 1 , @UserID)";
```